# Android use CFB

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I'm trying to encode my String with AES and CFB. If im doing this

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding");
```

, it works fine. But if i'm using "AES/CFB/NoPadding" instead of "AES", then the same String with the same password is different. Here is my Code:

```
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(cryptPassword.getBytes(), "AES");

        byte[] cryptByte = cryptString.getBytes("UTF8"); 

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding");

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] hans = cipher.doFinal(cryptByte);


        cryptString = Base64.encodeToString(hans,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Do you mean you tried `new SecretKeySpec(cryptPassword.getBytes(), "AES/CFB/NoPadding");`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the question is about the difference of `Cipher.getInstance("AES")` and `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding")`:

For [Oracle JDK the default mode/padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258047/java-default-crypto-aes-behavior) when you do not specify them in the transformation string is "ECB/PKCS5Padding", meaning that `Cipher.getInstance("AES")` is the same as `Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding")`.

The result of encoding some data with AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding is predictably different from encoding the same data with AES/CFB/NoPadding.

To minimize the confusion you should always specify the full transformation with explicit mode and padding values.