# Java DES Wrong Encryption

Tags: java, encryption, des

I have coded DES in Java using builtin Libraries but I am not getting the right Encryption Result. Please explain me where I am making a mistake

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String l = "0e329232ea6d0d73";

        byte[] a = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(l);

        try{
            DESKeySpec dks = new DESKeySpec(a);
            SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
            SecretKey sk = skf.generateSecret(dks);
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sk);
        String M = "8787878787878787";
        byte[] b = c.doFinal(M.getBytes());

        System.out.println(new String(b));
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sk);
        System.out.println(new String(c.doFinal(b)));
        }
        catch(Exception e)

        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }   
    }

}
```

HexaDecimal 16 Digit Key: 0e329232ea6d0d73 
Plain Text: 8787878787878787
Encryption : –m^MúÊ'+–m^MúÊ'+©ôËÓ—

Desired Encryption: 0000000000000000

This is what I am saying the answer in the encrypted output in online calculator is 0000, and mine is completely different:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by desired result? Is it desired encrypted message or desired decrypted message?

Comment: desired encrypted message

Comment: http://www.emvlab.org/descalc/

I was matching my results with this DES calculator . and it doesn't matches with mine

Comment: The desired result of decryption is 87878787..., not 00000000... and you don't state any basis for your apparent expectation that the result of encryption will be all zeros either, which is most improbable. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Just edited it . Sorry .
I meant the Encryption should be 0000000000

Comment: 1. Don't use DES, it is no longer considered secure, it has been superseded byAES. 2. The result of encryption is an array of bytes, not characters, if you need to display encrypted data use hexadecimal. 3. How do you expect  `0000000000000000` as the encrypted result. 4. Do not use ECB mode, it is insecure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Comment: @EJP Actually what i am trying to is to encrypt 87878787... 
with the above mentioned 16 digit hexadecimal key . Whose Encrypted value should be 00000..... Which is the right Encrypted answer. But what when i try to encrypt with my code it just gives some really different answers as mentioned above .

Comment: @zaph can you explain how i will do this . ? and yes i know it has been superseded by AES already but i am just working on DES .

Comment: For the third time, why do you think the result should be all zeros? I repeat that this is most improbable. And are these binary zeroes or ASCII zeros?

Comment: Why DES since you kow it is no longer secure? Is this homework?

Comment: Yes i already know that it is not secure . yes this is my homework but my code isn't giving the right answers. 

let me share the picture of online calculator what i am trying to say .

Comment: @EJP Strangly enbough the output **is** hex `0000000000000000 `: [DES CALCULATOR](http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/descalc/index?key=0e329232ea6d0d73&iv=0000000000000000&input=8787878787878787&mode=ecb&action=Encrypt&output=)

Comment: @user2747596 Please econsider using variable names that mean something such as `key`, `data`, etc.

Comment: General advice: **Always use a fully qualified Cipher string.** `Cipher.getInstance("DES");` may result in different ciphers depending on the default security provider. It most likely results in `"DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"`, but it doesn't have to be. If it changes, you'll lose compatibility between different JVMs. For reference: [Java default Crypto/AES behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6258047/1816580)

Comment: **Never use [ECB mode](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Comment: **Don't use DES nowadays.** It only provides 56 bit of security. AES would be a much better, because it's more secure with the lowest key size of 128 bit. There is also a practical limit on the maximum ciphertext size with DES. See [Security comparison of 3DES and AES](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/26179/45523).

Comment: The IV must be unpredictable for CBC mode (read: random). Don't use a static IV, because that makes the cipher deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. An attacker who observes ciphertexts can determine when the same message prefix was sent before. The IV is not secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext. Usually, it is simply prepended to the ciphertext and sliced off before decryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`byte[] b = c.doFinal(M.getBytes());`

to

`byte[] b = c.doFinal(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(M));`

Besides, use mode ECB in your code (because you marked ECB in your picture). Like:

```
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/NoPadding");
```

The [String.getBytes()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()) encodes the String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset, storing the result into a new byte array. In your case which is an array of length 16 containing values `56 55 56 55...` [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) representation of `8787...`

What you need is converting the Hex `8787...` to binary.

Comment: Thanks man for saving my life .. it worked for me .
ok i have another question. how would i convert normal string to hexa

Comment: You mean [Converting A String To Hexadecimal In Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923863/converting-a-string-to-hexadecimal-in-java)?

Comment: @user2747596 And "platform's default charset" is probably not what you want, especially since it can change and if you don't know what it is you can't communicate that the person who has to decrypt your text.

Answer (score 1):

The data is: hex `8787878787878787` and needs to be converted to binary.
`

Comment: Convert the hax characters strig to `byte[]` data.

Comment: did you mean Converting 
M to hexa binary ?

Comment: can you please explain what you are trying to say ?Because i am not getting you on this

Answer (score 0):

The input to that online calculator is stated to be hex, which implies a data convertion. You aren't doing any hex conversion in your code: you're just providing base-10 digits in ASCII.

Comment: Actually hex-ASCII not base-10 digits and binary is needed.

Comment: @zaph It's only 'hex-ASCII', whatever that may be, if the recipient so treats it, which it doesn't. Binary is needed as an input to the encryption, but hex is a representation of binary. Base-10 digits in ASCII are also a representation of binary, but of the wrong binary value in this case.

Comment: It turns out that both the data and key are in hex-ascii.

Comment: The above answer just solved my issue you were right it was the issue of M.getbytes[] it wasn't in hexa. Thanks for the answers