# Decryption failed after Encrypting File using AES in Android N(Nougat)

Tags: android, encryption, aes, android-7.0-nougat, secret-key

Well, I was about to encrypt a file from SDcard on user's order and Of course decrypt it back after that. well after a bit of searching I found out how to do it in android using "AES". everything was fine until users give me feedback about decryption Failure on Android Nougat! I checked and Unfortunately they were right :(

App was doing fine on Lollipop and Kitkat but not "NOUGAT"!

I checked the Log (as the first thing to do which comes to mind) and I saw this:

> - New versions of the Android SDK no longer support the Crypto provider.
> - If your app was relying on setSeed() to derive keys from strings, you
> - should switch to using SecretKeySpec to load raw key bytes directly OR
> - use a real key derivation function (KDF). See advice here :
> - http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/06/security-crypto-provider-deprecated-in.html

And I kind of freaked out because I was exactly using Crypto-Provider!!!

```
public static byte[] generateKey(String password) throws Exception {
    byte[] keyStart = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("[SHA1PRNG][1]", "Crypto");
    random.setSeed(keyStart);
    kgen.init(128, random);
    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    return skey.getEncoded();
}
```

Then I find some Talks about this on SO: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36813098/securerandom-provider-crypto-unavailable-in-android-n-for-deterministially-gen), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42780406/security-crypto-provider-deprecated-in-android-n-does-following-code-needs-an)

[developer](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/06/security-crypto-provider-deprecated-in.html) site says we should no longer use crypto-provider for generation of Key for AES because:

> This provider only provided an implementation of the algorithm
>   “SHA1PRNG” for instances of SecureRandom. The problem is that the
>   SHA1PRNG algorithm is not cryptographically strong.

and instead we should generate key like this:

```
public byte[] generateKeyForAES(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    /* Store these things on disk used to derive key later: */
    int iterationCount = 1000;
    int saltLength = 32; // bytes; should be the same size as the output (256 / 8 = 32)
    int keyLength = 256; // 256-bits for AES-256, 128-bits for AES-128, etc  
    /* When first creating the key, obtain a salt with this: */
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] salt = new byte[saltLength];
    random.nextBytes(salt);  
    /* Use this to derive the key from the password: */
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount, keyLength);
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    byte[] keyBytes = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec).getEncoded();
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

    return key.getEncoded();
}
```

As a good boy I replaced new way of generating key but it didn't work!!! (bad google) then I start to take a good look at this code and I realized that because every time we run this method, "salt" is generating "RANDOM"ly and we couldn't generate a same key twice. So you either save salt! after first time it is generated Or use an static salt. well I used an static salt :)

```
byte[] salt = {(byte) 0xA4, (byte) 0x0B, (byte) 0xC8, (byte) 0x34, (byte) 0xD6, (byte) 0x95, (byte) 0xF3, (byte) 0x13};
```

As you may guess, Yes it did NOT worked either! what I mean is it did decrypt the file but it was corrupted! NOT the same file was retrieved!

It's been a WEEK since I face this problem and gone through a LOT of way to solve it but none of them work.

There are a lot of Talks on SO which is about "being Unable to decrypt via AES" but there were either suggesting a way that didn't work or were irrelevant!

some says its a problem from Transformation Algorithm in initializing Cipher after generating key and instead of this:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
```

we should do it like:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

but after that decryption even Fails to Decrypt from the beginning and it is worse than decrypting some corrupted file (with the same size of course)!

After I became really exhausted I think that forget about all Security risks and just make it work!!!
Then as  @artjom-b say in his [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36813098/securerandom-provider-crypto-unavailable-in-android-n-for-deterministially-gen) I tried to import `CryptoProvider` class locally in my project and then even if Android delete it completely, it will work in my project!!!

I just copy [CryptoProvider](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-5.1.1_r37/luni/src/main/java/org/apache/harmony/security/provider/crypto/CryptoProvider.java), [SHA1PRNG_SecureRandomImpl](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-5.1.1_r37/luni/src/main/java/org/apache/harmony/security/provider/crypto/SHA1PRNG_SecureRandomImpl.java) and of course all related class and put it in a package in my source code, then
,back to earlier way that I use to generate key for AES, I change generate key method as follows:

```
public static byte[] generateKey(String password) throws Exception {
    byte[] keyStart = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", new CryptoProvider());
    random.setSeed(keyStart);
    kgen.init(128, random);
    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    return skey.getEncoded();
}
```

As you may noticed the way `SucureRandom` is being initialized is changed! and insted of `"crypto"` I reference to my local provider and turn it like:

```
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", new CryptoProvider());
```

As the Serial of my failures in getting a Simple encryption on Android N to work follows, again it didn't work. I mean it did decrypting but the file was Corrupted again!

I really really appretiate any Help and I wonder If anyone face a same problem and knows how to fix it!?

Comment: Your existing approach for deriving keys from passwords is a broken approach. When you switch to a new approach of deriving keys, don't expect the new keys to be able to decrypt files encrypted with keys derived with the old approach.

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen if I get you corrent you mean that a file which is encrypted via "crypto" way of getting key won't be decrypted via new way of deriving key using  salt! But I did both Encrypting and Decrypting Again using new Approach of deriving a Key.

Comment: How you have generated the keys, don't impact your capability to decrypt what you just encrypted. But do you actually derive the same key ? If you method for deriving the key involves a salt, you then need to use the same salt for that key each time, so that you generate the same key.

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen Yes, I'm pretty sure that keys are the same because I use same salt (a fix array of bytes).