# java Encrypt method equivalent in node js crypto

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, encryption, cryptography

I have java encryption function code as

```
public String encrypt(String Data, String keySet) throws Exception {
    byte[] keyByte = keySet.getBytes();
    Key key = generateKey(keyByte);

    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key); //2
    byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes()); //1
    byte[] encryptedByteValue = new Base64().encode(encVal); //3
    String encryptedValue = new String(encryptedByteValue); //4
    return encryptedValue;
}

private static Key generateKey(byte[] keyByte) throws Exception {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyByte, "AES");
    return key;
}
```

Now I am trying to implement the same in NodeJs using crypto module
code is: -

```
//buf is string data that i want to encrypt

function makeEncrypt(buf, callback) {
    var enckey = "encryptionkey";
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, enckey)
    var crypted = cipher.update(buf, 'utf8', 'base64')
    crypted += cipher.final('base64');

    console.log("encrypted data is : " + crypted.toString());
    callback(null, crypted);
}
```

But the encrypted data returned by both functions is different what I am doing wrong? if anyone can help!! thanks in advance.

Comment: Your node.js code is incomplete.

Comment: General advice: **Always use a fully qualified Cipher string.** `Cipher.getInstance("AES");` may result in different ciphers depending on the default security provider. It most likely results in `"AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"`, but it doesn't have to be. If it changes, you'll lose compatibility between different JVMs. For reference: [Java default Crypto/AES behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6258047/1816580)

Comment: **Never use [ECB mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Comment: `crypto.createCipher` takes a password and not a key. If you want to supply a key, use `crypto.createCipheriv`

Comment: @Artjom B. I cannot make changes in java code as it is already implemented I only need to convert the above code to nodejs and the output should be same.

and cypto.createCipheriv requires a random iv each time while encrypting but in java code we are not using any random key or anything like that so i think the output will never match.

Comment: `cypto.createCipheriv` does not require an IV when using ECB mode. It can be empty: `""`

Comment: thnks now it is working perfectly :-)